# Segmentation fault/Dev C crashing

Tags: c, dev-c++, minesweeper

Hey guys so Im trying to do a homework and I cant find the fatal error on my program all day long.Let me explain :
Firstly,you give the number of rows,col then the cells of the array (only "." for free spaces and "*" for mines, all in one row without spaces) then the crashing happens.

```
main(){
    int  i,col,row,count,N,M,j;
    char **p;
    printf("Give number of rows\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Give number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&M);
    p=malloc(N*sizeof(char *));   //Saving room for the array
    if (p==NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i=0;i < N ; ++i){
        p[i] = malloc (M * sizeof(char));
        if (*(p+i) == NULL)
            return -1;
    }
    for (i=0; i< N;++i){
        for ( j = 0 ; j < M ;++j)
            scanf("%c",&p[i][j]); //Insert "*" for mines and the rest with "."
    }
    for (row=1; row<= N;++row){           //Here the things get messy
                for ( col = 1 ; col <= M ;++col){
                    if(p[row][col]=='.'){
                        count = 0 ;
                        if(p[row][col+1]=='*' && col < M)
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row][col-1]=='*' && col > 1)
                           count=count+1;
                        if(p[row+1][col]=='*' && row < N)
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row-1][col]=='*' && row > 1)
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row+1][col+1]=='*' && (row < N && col < M))
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row+1][col-1]=='*' && (row < N && col > 1))
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row-1][col+1]=='*' && ( row > 1 && col < M))
                            count=count+1;
                        if(p[row-1][col-1]=='*' && ( row > 1 && col > 1))
                            count=count+1;
                        printf("%d ", count);
                    }
                    printf("* ");           
                }
                printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
     for (i=0; i< N;++i){       
                for ( j = 0 ; j < M ;++j)
                        printf("%c ",p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
     }
    for (i = 0 ; i <N ; ++i)
        free(p[i]);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's ethical to help with one's homework.... And to be honest, all real programmers learnt their first valuable lesson by tracking down a seg fault, you probably shall not let people take away this chance from you

Comment: Sure it is. OP clearly stated it was homework, stated the problem, and showed reasonable effort to provide details.

Comment: Provided code is not compiling. Use debugger to detect problem. Basing on source code and description I assume that problem is `array out of bound`

Comment: Im struggling 4 hours with it and I cant find a solution thats why I ended up posting it here.I would debug it if I could like the rest of my homeworks.

Comment: Check return values of `scanf`. Initialize all variables. Use braces `{}` even with single statements after `if` etc. After that start to really hunt for the bug.

Comment: Your code seems to contain `p[row]` with `row==N`, which is out of bounds, undefined behaviour. If it crashes, it means you got lucky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, here's what I did to debug (actually I saw the problem in the code and just verified this way, but this will be useful to you).

1. Add `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` at the head of the file.
2. `gcc -Wall -O0 -g x.c -o x` to compile with debug and no optimisation.

I then used following to run within `gdb`:

```
gdb x
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/amb/so/x
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
Give number of rows
1
Give number of columns
1

.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007d4 in main () at x.c:25
25                      if(p[row][col]=='.'){
(gdb) print row
$1 = 1
(gdb) print col
$2 = 1
(gdb)
```

See how in less than 10 seconds it showed me where the error was?

You have two problems:

```
for (row=1; row<= N;++row){           //Here the things get messy
            for ( col = 1 ; col <= M ;++col){
                if(p[row][col]=='.'){
```

The `SEGV` appears here as you access `p[N][M]`, but the indices of `p` can only go from `0` to `N-1` and `0` to `M-1` respectively. This loop should probably read:

```
for (row=0; row < N;++row){           //Here the things get messy
            for ( col = 0 ; col < M ;++col){
                if(p[row][col]=='.'){
```

(note change to start at `row=0`, and `row < N` not `row <= M` and similarly for `col`).

The second problem you have is to do with what to do at the edges:

Lines like this:

```
if (p[row][col-1]=='*' && col > 1)
   count=count+1;
```

should have the `col > 1` condition *first* so they don't evaluate the array element unless the condition is true. Also, as `col` goes `0..M-1`, you want

```
if ((col > 0) && (p[row][col-1]=='*'))
    count=count+1;
```

Note I've put in some brackets to avoid any ambiguity.

The same applies when looking at the other edges:

```
if (p[row][col+1]=='*' && col < M)
    count=count+1;
```

should be:

```
if ((col < M-1) && (p[row][col+1]=='*'))
    count=count+1;
```

That should get you going. But *learn to use a debugger*.

Comment: Thanks for the long post :)
After your comments its running smoothly!Well,the teacher said he was going to teach us about dbg on the next lesson so I didnt bother searching on net.From the beggining I was correcting my programs with random printf >.<
PS:I just missed the header files on my post.

Comment: Up voting for this awesomeness and hope people will link future c "homework" questions to this post if proper. Forgive me that I've only commented in main post instead spending time to come up with an answer like this. Also I hope this can serve as a good simple tutorial on debugger so people will use less of SO as answer machine to homeworks

Comment: Just highlighting one point in this excellent post in case OP missed it; you must pay attention to compiler warnings because if you have a problem in your code, often the compiler will give you a clue. The code you posted should issue warnings about `printf` and `malloc` being undeclared (the latter is particularly serious).

Comment: @MattMcNabb As far as I remember there were no warnings on dev-c.However,didn't check it on linux.